# returning the highest value in the key : value pair in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in need of some assistance in this code problem from a MOOC on python programming that I'm taking. This is just for self-learning, and not for any graded coursework. Could you please provide some guidance. I am stuck. Thanks in advance for your help.

The problem statement is below:
Write a function called most_active. most_active should take one parameter, a dictionary. The dictionary's keys will all be strings representing people's names. The dictionary's
values will be integers representing days of activity on a course forum.

most_active should return the name of the most active student in the class. That is, most_active should return the key whose value is the highest in the dictionary.

For example:

```
some_dictionary = {"Joyner, David": 14, "Chopra, Deepak": 22, "Winfrey, Oprah": 17}
most_active(some_dictionary) -> "Chopra, Deepak"
```

The key "Chopra, Deepak" has the highest value (22), so the function returns "Chopra, Deepak". You may assume there will not be a tie for most active.

Add your code here!

```
def most_active(dictionary):
```

Below are some lines of code that will test your function. You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your function with different inputs.

If your function works correctly, this will originally
print:
Chopra, Deepak

```
some_dictionary = {"Joyner, David": 14, "Chopra, Deepak": 22, "Winfrey, Oprah": 17}
print(most_active(some_dictionary))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way:

```
most_active = max(some_dictionary,key=some_dictionary.get))
print(most_active)
```

output

```
>>> Chopra, Deepak
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all of the items:

```
kmax = None
vmax = None
for k, v in d.items():
    if vmax is None or v > vmax:
        kmax = k
        vmax = v
```

Note: The other answers use a functional approach that is more elegant but requires understanding  the necessary concepts.